# How to detect out of space error when mapping shared memory

Tags: mmap

The code is as follows:

```
fd = shm_open("Name", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
if (fd < 0) {
    return -1;
}

rv = ftruncate(fd, 10 * 1024 * 1024);
if (rv != 0) {
    return -1;
}

addr = mmap(NULL, 10 * 1024 * 1024, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
if (addr == MAP_FAILED) {
    return -1;
}

/* Access the shared memory here and the program crashes */
```

Note that the size of /dev/shm is 30MB, and it's full before running the program.  Instead of crashing, I would like to catch the out of space error and fail gracefully.  However, mmap() doesn't return an error in this case.  Is there a way for me to detect the out of space error?

Comment: I doubt we can provide much help if you don't provide the actual code you are using. Are you checking the result value of `shm_open`? What about `ftruncate`?

Comment: I updated the code to be more clear about error checking.

Comment: That looks correct to me (albeit I've never done anything like this; I either use `shm_*()` or `mmap()`, not both in tandem.) What about the actual code that fails? Are you catching `SIGBUS`?